# Clojure: Reversing the parameters of contains? for use in condp

Tags: clojure

I discovered this clojure problem today:

```
(condp contains? some-set
   "foo"   "foo's in thar"
   "bar"   "bar's in thar"
   "t'aint thar")
```

The idea is to return the string under the first match where `some-set` contains a value. If none of the values is in the set, it returns the last value. Problem is, the `contains?` function takes the collection first then the key and `condp` needs the key first.

I "fixed" it by writing a function:

```
(defn reverse-params [f] (fn [a b] (f b a))
```

and substituting a call to it:

```
(condp (reverse-params contains?) some-set
   "foo"   "foo's in thar"
   "bar"   "bar's in thar"
   "t'aint thar")
```

Which works, but my question is am I missing some better way to do this (maybe by using `some`)? I could use `cond` but I figured this way saves me some typing.

Comment: the common name for the `reverse-params` function is [`flip`](https://gist.github.com/micmarsh/bcbe19c9de8bb7a471bf)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nope, you're not missing something. This is a normal way of going about it.
I often use an anonymous function for this if it will only be used once.

```
(condp #(contains? %2 %1) some-set
   "foo"   "foo's in thar"
   "bar"   "bar's in thar"
   "t'aint thar")
```

This problem also comes up when threading things with the `->` and `->>` macros. In those cases I'll often use the `as->` macro to give the threaded value a name